# Postgres similar query taking different time, not sure what's wrong

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

We have a query that runs on several different child tables created hourly and inherited from a base table, say tab_name1 and tab_name2. The query was working fine, but suddenly it started to perform badly for all the Childs since a particular date.

This is the query which works fine till `tab_name_20180621*`, not sure what happened after that.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tab_name_201806220300
WHERE
    id = 201806220300
    AND col1 IN (
        SELECT
            col1
        FROM
            tab_name2_201806220300
        WHERE
            uid = 5452
            AND id = 201806220300
    );
```

The analyze output shows something like this, there's huge  difference in execution time.

```
#1
Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.00..84762.11 rows=1 width=937) (actual time=117.599..117.599 rows=0 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (tab_name_201806210100.col1 = tab_name2_201806210100.col1)
  ->  Seq Scan on tab_name_201806210100  (cost=0.00..31603.56 rows=1 width=937) (actual time=117.596..117.596 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (log_id = '201806220100'::bigint)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 434045
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..53136.74 rows=1454 width=41) (never executed)
        ->  Seq Scan on tab_name2_201806210100  (cost=0.00..53129.47 rows=1454 width=41) (never executed)
              Filter: ((uid = 5452) AND (log_id = '201806210100'::bigint))
Planning time: 1.490 ms
Execution time: 117.723 ms


#2
Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.00..10299.31 rows=48 width=1476) (actual time=1082.255..47041.945 rows=671 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (tab_name_201806220100.col1 = tab_name2_201806220100.col1)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 252444174
  ->  Seq Scan on tab_name_201806220100  (cost=0.00..4023.69 rows=95 width=1476) (actual time=0.008..36.292 rows=64153 loops=1)
        Filter: (log_id = '201806220100'::bigint)
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..6274.19 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.000..0.264 rows=3935 loops=64153)
        ->  Seq Scan on tab_name2_201806220100  (cost=0.00..6274.19 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.464..55.475 rows=3960 loops=1)
              Filter: ((log_id = '201806220100'::bigint) AND (uid = 5452))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 140592
Planning time: 1.024 ms
Execution time: 47042.234 ms
```

I don't know what to infer from this and how to proceed from here. Could you help me?

Comment: So both queries are the same but different tables? Are you indexing the same? Might need to show table schema: `\d tablename` in psql.

Comment: Are the tables growing with time? If yes, it is natural that, the bigger the tables get, the more time the query will take. The question is "how much slower is the query not? (e.g. before it took 1 sec. and now 5 hours). Still, I would start by checking the use of indices of the tables (assuming that you do have some indices, do you?).

Comment: @Parfait : There's no index on those columns used in where clause  for both the tables, So the difference is unexplained even thought there isn't much of a difference in data. Also, the main query actually uses joins, Although I have simplified the problem here, the problem exists in both cases.

Comment: @FDavidov : There is no exponential growth in data.  In fact, even the number of rows in both the child table is  approximately same

Comment: @itguy ... can you still post the result of `\d tablename` for both tables?

Comment: @Parfait : I won't be able to post the complete result from the command as i'm not allowed to do so. If you tell me some specific items that you want to see, i may only post that.

Comment: @itguy, Your comment is not addressing the points I made. The fact that the tables are the same or different sizes has no consequences on performance. You are saying that performance is degrading, and an increase in the number of records might be one of the sources for the degradation. Also, you are not quantifying the fast/slow contrast.